# Who leaked the Deadpool footage?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

Deadpool has taken a long time to make and Ryan Renolds has stated that it took over 11 years from its concept. So who leaked the footage for deadpool?

[Ryan Reynolds Recounts Making of 'Deadpool': "Thank God for the Internet"](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/ryan-reynolds-recounts-making-deadpool-882694)

> For me, it has been an 11-year journey," said Reynolds of the
>   long-gestating project. "It felt like a shitty relationship. We would
>   be at the altar and then the wedding would be off and on and off, and
>   then finally we did it

Reynolds also noted that it was the internet that helped get the go ahead for production:

> Thank god for the Internet, and thank god for the fans. They pushed
>   this movie over the hump

Comment: My feeling is that no-one 'leaked' it. It was almost certainly released as part of a coordinated attempt ny the studio to make the film into a "***viral sensation***" and "***the film they didn't want you to see***". Note how little other footage, props, scripts,  etc have leaked from Marvel and then compare how they acted over the deadpool leak as compared to how they flipped their shit when the Wolverine preprint leaked.

Comment: @Valorum, I am not so sure. It was a rated R film and I think Fox really was against it.

Comment: Viral marketing 101 is "Leak it to get extra publicity". Hence all the sextapes that get traced back to the starlet's production company.

Comment: @Valorum, could well be the case. To test the waters , so to speak.

Comment: @CreationEdge, So having the internet help get the go ahead for production from the leaked footage has no connection. Could have fooled me.

Comment: @CreationEdge, sure , I am asking who leaked the footage and the body of the question states how the internet helped getting the go ahead for production. What more do you want?

Comment: @CreationEdge, feel free to edit the question to how you feel it should be. I won't complain.

Comment: The cynic in me says that they planned this all along. What's more likely; a) that the studio intentionally leaked it to get some free publicity or b) That Ryan Reynolds leaked it because the film was stuck in development hell. Assuming b, what response do you think would have been likely from Marvel if they thought there was even a sniff of him having leaked their film to the internet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Well this has been a source of controversy, some say it was Tim Miller or or someone close to him at Blur Studios, but it may actually have been Ryan Reynolds himself:

[We May Finally Know Who Leaked The Deadpool Footage](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/We-May-Finally-Know-Who-Leaked-Deadpool-Footage-112687.html)

> While Miller hasn’t publicly said he was behind the leak, numerous
>   sources point to him or one of his colleagues at Blur. I have no
>   smoking-gun proof other than my typically very reliable sources on
>   such matters. But if so, it was a bold move from a filmmaker who had
>   nothing to lose and everything to gain.

Ryan Reynolds has stated in an interview on *The Tonight Show with Jimmy Fallon* that is was it was one of 4 people, him, Rhett reese, Paul Wernick or Tim Miller, but it might have actually been the actor himself who leaked it:

> We developed the script 6 years ago, wrote this fantastic script , it
>   leaked online and Deadpool fans went nuts for it. So the studio
>   granted us a small amount of money to make a test footage that we
>   shot, which then sat on the shelf for 4 years as it does and they did
>   not do anything with it, as it does and just under 2 years ago it
>   leaked accidentally onto the internet...  Well here is the thing, the
>   deadpool fans freaked out and overwhelmed Fox and Fox basically had to
>   green light the movie, the problem was that the footage was owned by
>   Fox and sort of illegal that....**I know that one of us did it, there**
>   **me (Ryan Reynolds) Rhett reese, Paul Wernick, Tim Miller the director**,
>   one of us did it. **We said that someone should leak it.**